# Not visible label text in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I have created a custom table for the very basic. I made a tabbar controller.

**FoglalasTableViewCell.h**

```js
@interface FoglalasTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *datumLabelFoglalas;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *adminNevekLabelFoglalas;

@end
```

**FoglalasTableViewCell.m**

```js
#import "FoglalasTableViewCell.h"

@implementation FoglalasTableViewCell


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

```js
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdent = @"foglalas";
    
    FoglalasTableViewCell *Cellw = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdent];
    
    if (!Cellw) {
        Cellw = [[FoglalasTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdent];
        // Cellw = [[FoglalasTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdent];
    }
    
    if (Cellw.backgroundView == nil) {
    
        if ([foglaltArr[indexPath.row] isEqual: @0]) {
            [Cellw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        } else if ([foglaltArr[indexPath.row] isEqual: @1]) {
            [Cellw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        }
    }
    
    NSLog(@"%d. foglaltArr : %@",indexPath.row, [foglaltArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    NSLog(@"%d orakArr %@",indexPath.row,orakArr[indexPath.row]);

    Cellw.datumLabelFoglalas.text = [foglaltArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Cellw.adminNevekLabelFoglalas.text = @"blah..";

    return Cellw;
    
}
```

I plugged the datasource.
It changed the cells background colour.
But the labels don't get the data sources.
I don't understand why get the background the source, and labels why don't get!? I do not know how to solve it.
Please help me.

![background source is visible][1]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here (I guess you're not using prototype cell)

```
Cellw = [[FoglalasTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdent];
```

You are not loading your xib here you are just creating the `FoglalasTableViewCell` object which has `datumLabelFoglalas` and `adminNevekLabelFoglalas` as `nil`

Use

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FoglalasTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
Cellw = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

For reference you can check [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

---

**Edit:** For protype cell, change the class name and identifier of the cell in storyboard and use the below method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdent = @"foglalas";

    FoglalasTableViewCell *Cellw = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdent];

    if (Cellw.backgroundView == nil) {

        if ([foglaltArr[indexPath.row] isEqual: @0]) {
            [Cellw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        } else if ([foglaltArr[indexPath.row] isEqual: @1]) {
            [Cellw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%d. foglaltArr : %@",indexPath.row, [foglaltArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    NSLog(@"%d orakArr %@",indexPath.row,orakArr[indexPath.row]);

    Cellw.datumLabelFoglalas.text = [foglaltArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Cellw.adminNevekLabelFoglalas.text = @"blah..";

    return Cellw;
}
```

Comment: Thank You tutorial, but not solved my problems, please look my error log:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CEB07188-72C4-4A3A-BCE0-14709418D5EE/BBQ.app> (loaded)' with name 'FoglalasTableViewCell''
I use storyboard.

Comment: You're using storyboard and perhaps you're creating cell on storyboard which is called prototype cell.

Comment: Yes it is. I use storyboard, and make cell in sb.

Comment: Sorry, little not good: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Answer (score 1):

i would declare the properties as `nonatomic, strong`. Also i would `synthesize` them.

Also check you connected the elements with your view.

At last just call the nib

```
FoglalasTableViewCell *cell = (FoglalasTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FoglalasTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (FoglalasTableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: What is MasterCell? This class?

Comment: @bolo sorry, i copied this from a block of the project in which im working in. I edited it to `FoglalasTableViewCell `

Comment: Thank You, your speed. What is error? Please, You look at: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/973FEA8A-CF7E-43AA-9075-C003457BBF8B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BE5E55E-CC73-4D58-9450-DC70BE0C5A3E/BBQ.app> (loaded)' with name 'FoglalasTableViewCell''

Comment: do you have the cell in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I have cell in storyboard.

Comment: @bolo if youre using storyboard as source of your custom cell please check [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/). Anyway, for this, i prefer to create a xib file

Answer (score 0):

In main.storyboard select your table view cell and fill Identifier field  "foglalas"